# How can I exclude a specific set of files from certain rules?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to rewrite the URLs on my site from .php to .html and I have some other rules that are interfering with what I would like to do.

The code below shows all the rules working but I have some flat PHP pages that I would like to turn into .html pages.  An example would be history.php to history.html.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


##Vendor Pages
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html?$ vendors2.php?vendorslug=$3&locationslug=$1&categoryslug=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

##Listing Pages
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html?$ listings.php?locationslug=$1&categoryslug=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*/)?history\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)\.html?$ $1.php [L,NC]

##Locations Pages
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)\.html?$ locations.php?locationslug=$1&Submit=Submit [L,QSA,NC]
```

Currently, the code appears to be confused with other rules because it is attempting to return the page as a "Location Page" because of the rules.

There are several pages that I need to turn into .html (history.php, news.php, maps.php, resources.php, trivia.php and others).

Any constructive help is appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you turn on rewrite logging...

Comment: arkascha, thanks for the tip.  I have yet to try rewrite logging.  I will read up on it and experiment with it.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you're simply not matching the RewriteCond's.  Your `RewriteCond` to check that the file exists is likely being interpreted as, say, "is `/home/username/public_html/history.html.php` a file?", which will fail.

I would suggest that rather than include several `RewriteCond`'s before your rule, you could replace it with a single `RewriteRule`, before your `##Locations Pages`. Something like the following:

```
RewriteRule (history|news|maps|resources)\.html $1.php [L]
```

Note that this could make for a loooong line if you have a lot of entries, so you could just split it into several rules.

If you're looking for the request being in the "root":

```
RewriteRule ^(history|news|maps|resources)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: This worked just as I needed it to.  Thank you very much!  I appreciate your help.